# Spring Security ACL - create permission

Tags: spring-security, acl

I can use Spring Security ACL with permissions on entity but I'd like to know how to test if a user has access to the "create" (bit 2) permission on a class.

Something like :

```
aclPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(auth, clazz, "create")
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's SpEL annotations, e.g. `@PreAuthorize`, and override the `hasPermission` method of the `PermissionEvaluator` interface. If you're using bitwise permission masks, and the user's permissions (as an `int`) evaluate to '15' (`1111`), and the required permissions for the object are '6' (`0110`), you can do something like the following:

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetObject, Object requiredPermissions) {
    int permissionMask = MyUserClass.getMask();
    int permissionsRequired = Integer.valueOf(requiredPermissions.toString());
    return ((permissionMask | requiredPermissions) == permissionMask);
}
```

This will return true whenever the bits active in the object's permissions mask are active on the user's permissions. Then, you'd need to declare this custom permission evaluator in your `security.xml` file:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="my.project.package.CustomPermissionEvaluator"/>
```

Now, whenever you call `hasPermission()`, your custom evaluator will handle the request. Obviously, you can use whatever logic you like to evaluate permissions -- just make sure the return type is `boolean`, and the parameters to be passed match what you're sending (or evaluating against; be careful of format exceptions).

Note that your custom parameter must be passed as an `Object` to override `hasPermission()`; you could also overload the method by changing the signature to handle whatever parameter type you prefer (e.g. String or int), and the compiler *should* select the most specific signature. Since you're implementing the PermissionEvaluator interface, however, you'll have to include the given signature (Authentication, Object, Object) anyway, so unless you have some specific need to write an overload method, you may as well just override.

Comment: Hi @cabbagery, thanks for the answer but it's still not looking for a permission on a specific class...

Comment: Are you talking about class-level annotation-driven access, or are you talking about the objects in the ACL (the `acl_class` table)? Also, check out [Mark Serrano's ACL tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial.html) if you haven't already scoured it. I've used several of his tutorials in tandem with other resources and some experimentation of my own, and found it immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, and sadly, there is no "out of the box" solutions.

One way to do it, if your domain model allow for it, is to add the create permission to the parent object you want to create

For example, imagine you want to create an user for a client. You can add the create permission to the client for the user allowed to create user for this specific client. That the path I choose.

If your domain object doesn't allow for that, the only way I found to do it is:

- to create a new table `acl_class_entry`, wich list `acl_entry` equivalent but linked to an `acl_class` and not to an `acl_object_identity`
- Then you create your own permission evaluator, surcharging the method `boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission)` to check the permission against the `acl_class_entry` if `target_id` is null. This will allow you to check permission against a class by using the SPel expression `hasPermission(nulll, 'className', 'permission')`
- Of course, you will also need to create your own version of `AclService` for creating such permission.